# Simple Product with checkbox user defined quantity

Tags: custom-options, checkbox

So we sell a product in multiple strengths and sizes on our wholesale site. Product A comes in strength 1, 2, and 3. Currently the user has to select the bottle size via drop down then select strength via drop down and input quantity. This works but it takes the user a long time to place their order as they have to keep clicking the drop down and selecting the strength and input the quantity. We'd like to be able to utilize check boxes with user defined quantities for the strengths so the user can use the drop down for bottle size, then tick each strength, input the quantity they desire for each and add to cart. Each strength and bottle size would then be their own line item in the cart. Any feedback or someone looking to code this would be appreciate. Thanks!

Comment: any solution about that please?